# How to get the external files using Node.js and Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I cannot get the the external files links which are includes in index page using Node.js. Here is my code.

server.js:

```
var port=8888;
var express=require('express');
var http=require('http');
var morgan         = require('morgan');
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); // the session is stored in a cookie, so we use this to parse it
var app            = express();
var server=http.createServer(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(server);
//var admin=require('./route/route.js');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                     // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json())    // parse application/json
app.use(methodOverride());                  // simulate DELETE and PUT
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({secret:'odiyaDoctor'}));
app.get('/admin',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('admin/view/index.html');
});
server.listen(port);   
console.log('Magic happens on port'+port);          // shoutout to the user
```

Let me show my folder structure:

```
root-
  ->admin
      ->js
         ->angular.min.js
      ->css
         ->style.css
         ->responsive.css
      ->view
         ->index.html
      ->public
   ->server.js
   ->package.json
```

From the above structure says inside the root folder i have one folder called `admin`. Inside the admin folder there folders like `css,js,view etc` to contain the respective files.

admin/view/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head ng-app="doctorAdmin">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Welcome to Odia Doctor Admin Panel</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" /><!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" /><!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" /><!-- Style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" type="text/css" /><!-- Responsive -->  
<script src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="adminController/loginController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-image: url('images/resource/login-bg.jpg')">
    
<div class="login-sec" ng-controller="loginController">
    <div class="login-sec">
    <div class="login">
        <div class="login-form">
            <span><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></span>
            <h5><strong>Identify</strong> Yourself</h5>
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <fieldset><input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="logininputdiv" /><i class="fa fa-user"></i></fieldset>
                <fieldset><input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="logininputdiv" /><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i></fieldset>
                <label><input type="checkbox" />Remember me</label><button type="button" class="blue" onClick="document.location='dashboard.html'">LOG IN</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <span>Copyright © 2015 Odia Doctor</span>
    </div>
</div><!-- Log in Sec -->   

</body>

</html>
```

In the above file I have included some links and my problem is I am unable to fetch those.

Answer (score 0):

Add all your link in public folder because you set below code in server.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

This means that all your external file has relative path with in public folder sp put your css folder with in public folder if you don't want it in public folder than set below code

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

Comment: I did as per you.I put all `css,js etc` folder into `admin/public` folder and included the link like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />` but still getting the same issue.

Comment: add <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" /> and try

Comment: I added as per you but still same issue.

Comment: can you give me an output of this?? 'console.log('__dirname);'

Comment: I did it by doing like this `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/admin/public'));`. got the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116186/discussion-between-satya-and-nikhil-patel).